# CSS media:print include something that wasn't displayed on screen?

Tags: html, css

I have the following

```css
@media print {
  DIV {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="display:none">You can't see me!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I tried this, I still couldn't see "You can't see me!" when I print. How can I get this to show up for printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a class to your `div` so you can specify what needs to be seen when being printed:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="print-only">You can't see me!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your CSS would look like:

```
.print-only {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
  .print-only {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, from your code I can see you use an inline style of `display: none`. This will prevent the div from showing. Remove the inline style to correct this.

Comment: This worked, thank you! So this solved part of my problem. The other part being that for where I'm using this, I'm using jQuery.hide to hide things - But I'd like them to be available for print... Seems like I might have to hack jQuery.hide / toggle

Comment: @ControlAltDel Samuel's (implied) suggestion of using `!important` should be enough to override the inline style that jQuery will add, so you won't need to modify the jQuery.

Comment: @cjl750 I tried Samuel's suggestion before testing this one out. It didn't work for me (IE 11)

Comment: @cjl750 on your advice, I just tried it again, and it works! (I had my semi-colon in the wrong place) thank you for posting this comment and spurring me to take another look!